# Popup dialog in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a popup dialog which asks for an input and returns the value.

I included a popup component on the root component, above the app's router outlet

In the popup component, I have an open() method which changes a boolean I called "status", which the component has an *ngIf looking at (to control the popup's appearance).

If I create a service and use an Event Emitter, I can not get a return value of the form input.

Any advice?

https://gist.github.com/alshdavid/f783ad367bc1c77cb07412ba0ea2e099

EDIT: I apologise for being bad here - Turns out I had to use a redux-style data model

Comment: I placed the component as a provider in the app.module, however when I call it within the constructor of my service, it creates an instance rather than allowing me to interact with the class directly.

Perhaps I am going about this wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. 
I hope this code snippet illustrates what I am trying to do better.

https://gist.github.com/alshdavid/f783ad367bc1c77cb07412ba0ea2e099

Answer (score 1):

You've got a small error, in that `*ngFor` is for iterating through a collection. You want `*ngIf` instead.

In terms of how you would go about implementing a popup like this, that is quite a broad question. I'll try to put together an example later.

Comment: Thank you, changed it - was a little flustered earlier.

I have been recommended a redux-style approach, where I modify a central point of data in a service that is accessible by both things